# How to call methods in different parent interfaces using child class name?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am migrating a project from python to java. There is a multiple inheritanced python tool class, called `Util(TimeUtil, MathUtil, FileUtil, ...)`, it extend several `Util` classes. For example

```
# python
class MathUtil(object):
    @staticmethod
    def add(n, m):
        return n + m


class TimeUtil(object):
    @staticmethod
    def date_to_str():
        return '2022-01-01'


class Util(MathUtil, TimeUtil):
    @staticmethod
    def do_something():
        return

Util.add(1, 2)
```

Normally, I would call `Util.date_to_str()`, `Util.add()`, `Util.read_file()` in python, importing class `Util` is enough, and **I can call the static method of parent classes by the class name**

I want to separate util functions into different util class. Can you show me how to implement calling multiple parent static method with child class name (not instance) in java? If it is not the case, why?

#### What I have tried

Apparently I can not multiple **extend** other class in java.

I tried with interface, I put default methods in parent interfaces, and I **have to create an instance of the child class** to call the methods in parent class. It is not ok because it is a Util class, I want to use class name to call method, not instance of the class

```
import java.util.Date;

interface MathUtil {

    default int add(int n, int m){
        return n + m;
    }
}

interface TimeUtil{
    default String parseDate(Date date) {
        return "2022-01-01";
    }
}
public class Util implements MathUtil, TimeUtil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        expect code 
//         int add = Util.add(1, 2); 
//         compile error
//         Non-static method 'add(int, int)' cannot be referenced from a static context

        // actual code, it is compiled
        Util util = new Util();
        int add = util.add(1, 2);
    }
}
```

If I change default method in parent interface to static method, then I have to call the method with parent interface name like `MathUtil.add(1, 2)`, otherwise get compile error: **Static method may be invoked on containing interface class only**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a static method `add()` in a `MathUtil` class, then you call it with `MathUtil.add(...)`.

If you want to call an `add()` method like `Util.add(...)`, place it into the `Util` class.

In Java, you have to decide which of the two styles you want. You can't have both.

Comment: yeah, that is probably the reason. Then may I ask what is the point for interface extending other interface? for example if we want to use Child interface, we have to follow rules in both Child and Parent interface, is there any other benefit than this?

Comment: You might have a `Person` interface naming basic requirements (i.e. methods) for any person and a `Parent`, an `Employer`, an `Employee` interface, all extending `Person` and requiring methods specific to that type of person, plus an `EmployedFather` class implementing `Parent` plus `Employee`. And then this class needs to have method implementations for all the methods named in `Person`, `Parent` and `Employee`, and you can store instances of this class in variables typed `Object`, `Person`, `Parent`, `Employee` or `EmployedFather`.